# Java rest assured - No serializer found for class org.example.Place and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer

Tags: java, rest, serialization

could someone tell why this happens ?

Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.example.Place and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://example.com";
        

        Place place = new Place();

        Location location = new Location();
        location.setLat(434334.54);
        location.setLng(3545.43);
        place.setLocation(location);

        List<String> lista = Arrays.asList("ala", "ma");

        place.setAccuracy(50);
        place.setAddress("29, side layout, cohen 09");
        place.setLanguage("French");
        place.setPhone_number("(+91) 983 893 3937");
        place.setName("WEb site");
        place.setTypes(lista);
        place.setWebsite("www.web.pl");


        String resposnePost =
                given().relaxedHTTPSValidation()
                        .queryParam("key","qaclick123")
                        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .body(place)
                        .when()
                        .post("/maps/api/place/add/json")
                        .then()
                        .assertThat()
                        .statusCode(200)
                        .extract().response().asString();

        JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(resposnePost);

        String placeId = jsonPath.getString("place_id");

        String bodyDoMetodyPut = String.format("{\n" +
                "\"place_id\":\"%s\",\n" +
                "\"address\":\"70 Summer walk, USA\",\n" +
                "\"key\":\"qaclick123\"\n" +
                "}\n", placeId);


        String resposnePut = given().relaxedHTTPSValidation()
                .queryParam("key","qaclick123")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body(bodyDoMetodyPut)
                .when()
                .put("maps/api/place/update/json")
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body("msg", equalTo("Address successfully updated"))
                .extract().asString();

        JsonPath jsonPath2 = new JsonPath(resposnePut);

        String putAnswer = jsonPath2.getString("msg");

        System.out.println(putAnswer);
    }
```

Place class with setters

```
public class Place {

    Location location;
    int accuracy;
    String name;
    String phone_number;
    String address;
    List<String> types;
    String website;
    String language;
```

Location class with setters

```
public class Location {

    double lat;
    double lng;
```

POM file

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

could you help ?